# Pip Upgrade Installs Wrong Django Version: What to do?

Tags: django, version-control, pip

I was in the secure shell and decided to `--upgrade` one of the django apps I am using. I typed `pip install django-guardian --upgrade` and noticed that it was also downloading and unpacking an earlier version of Django than I am currently using: 1.3. Oops!

My debug screen shows that I am using django 1.4.2 and python 2.7, but since I `upgraded` guardian my app is working differently, perhaps because of conflicting django versions?? The important difference is when using apps like `django-ratings`. When voting using [django-ratings](https://github.com/Kronuz/django-ratings/blob/master/djangoratings/views.py#L128), no message is displayed when the user is re-directed and the vote is recorded:

```
def authentication_required_response(self, request, context):
    message = _("You must be logged in to vote.")
    response = HttpResponse(message)
    response.status_code = 403
    return response
```

This displays a blank page now. I did not change anything in my django app, but now it is behaving differently. How should I address this issue to return my app to its previous state before I mistakenly `--upgraded` and confused things? Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). It allows you to control the environment of each individual django app on your machine. You create a virtual environment, install the packages you want, then start up the environment before you start your app.

It can be as simple as listing your apps in a `requirements` file, then installing the `requirements` file in your virtualenv -

```
psycopg2==2.4.2
Django==1.4.3
Markdown==2.0
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.x/BeautifulSoup-3.0.7a.tar.gz
Pygments==1.3.1
Twisted==10.0.0
```

There's a great tutorial [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/).